# BigQuery. Adding a query as a column to a table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sql-insert, alter-table

SELECT
TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ended_at, started_at, MINUTE) AS trip_duration
FROM `coursera-practice-356200.Cyclistic_data.cycledata_202202-202301`

This is the query I am starting from.

I am new to SQL and I cannot seem to find how to do this. How do I add this new queried variable that I created, called trip_duration, as a column to the table that I created the query from?

I have tried INSERT and ALTER TABLE and nothing has worked. Most of what I have found only inserts individual values manually or it inserts a blank column. It seems to me to be something that should be easy, but I can't find a straightforward answer online. I think I am missing something

Answer (score 0):

You could put SELECT query after your INSERT clause

```
INSERT INTO table_name (trip_duration) 
SELECT TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ended_at, started_at, MINUTE) AS trip_duration FROM coursera-practice-356200.Cyclistic_data.cycledata_202202-202301
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried it after your response. It tried to create a row instead of a column.

Comment: Could you provide the table schema you have and what you want to achieve? You can use pivot or unpivot to modify it